# Converting right-linear grammar to left-linear grammar

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language

I have the following language: 
$$L := \{b(ab)^n a^m \mid  n, m \geq 0\}$$

and have created a *right-linear* grammar:

**Grammar**     $G(b(ab)^n a^m)$ 
 
**Terminals**       $a, b$ 
 
**Non-terminals**   $S, S_1, S_2$ 
 
**Start symbol**        $S$ 
 
**Productions**     
 
\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow b \\
S &\rightarrow bS_1 \\
S &\rightarrow bS_2 \\
S_1 &\rightarrow abS_1 \\
S_1 &\rightarrow abS_2 \\
S_1 &\rightarrow ab \\
S_2 &\rightarrow aS_2 \\
S_2 &\rightarrow a 
\end{align*}

I'm finding it hard trying to convert the above grammar into a *left-linear* grammar. Would appreciate if someone is able to help me. I've looked at videos on Youtube but I still cant seem to grasp it.

Am I right in thinking that the strings will be reversed or is there another way to do it?

Comment: What exactly are the constraints on $n$ and $m$ in the language?

Comment: Sorry. n, m >= 0

Comment: [Same question on Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/convert-a-right-linear-grammar-to-a-left-linear-grammar)

Answer (score 4):

HINT: I would simply start from scratch and write down a left-linear grammar directly from the regular expression $b(ab)^*a^*$ that defines the language. Clearly you need $S\to Sa$ and $S\to S_1$, where $S_1$ will ultimately generate strings of the form $b(ab)^*$. You’ll certainly need $S_1\to S_1ab$; can you work out the rest of the productions from here?

Answer (score 0):

switch between terminals and non terminals to get (A)r then make the inverse of the automaton to get((A)r)r then you can get the right linear grammar